# MySQL - Update cell value using foreign key

Tags: mysql, database

I've got a problem creating a database.
I'd like to update children table using it's foreign key referencing to mother table automatically.
It means that when data values are inserted into the mother table, the children table gets updated on the column that is the foreign key.
Here's the code i wrote:

```
drop database domowa_biblioteka;
create database domowa_biblioteka;
use domowa_biblioteka;

create table pozycje
    (
        lp_p mediumint NOT NULL auto_increment,
        nazwisko_autora char(30),
        tytul char(60),
        ilosc_stron int(4),
        cena_oryginalna int(4),
        na_sprzedaz enum('NIE','TAK'),
        sprzedana enum('NIE','TAK'),
        nr_pokoju mediumint,
        PRIMARY KEY (lp_p)
    )
    ;

create table kod_miedzynarodowy
    (
        lp_km mediumint,
        ISBN char(20),
        FOREIGN KEY (lp_km) REFERENCES pozycje (lp_p)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )
    ;

create table pokoje
    (
        nr_pokoju mediumint NOT NULL auto_increment,
        opis char(30),
        PRIMARY KEY (nr_pokoju)
    )
    ;
```

alter table pozycje ADD FOREIGN KEY (nr_pokoju) REFERENCES pokoje (nr_pokoju);

The thing is that the values of columns remain NULL after inserting data to rows.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Use a trigger, this is my comment.

Comment: Could you type your solution? I've been trying for over 3 hours now.

Comment: When you say, "values of columns remain NULL after inserting data to rows" - Which table's column values are null ?? parent or Child ?

Comment: The children ones.